# XSLT sum of variables in for-each loop doesn't work?

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I need to print the sum of multiple numbers in a for-each loop, I tried this syntax because the number could not be added if not parsed before, but the result remains perennially 0 even if the variable $result is rightly a number.

It is my sintax:

```html
<xsl:variable name="sum" select="0" />
<xsl:for-each select="Details/Package/Items">
 <xsl:variable name="int" select="substring-before(IWeight,',')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="dec" select="substring-after(IWeight, ',')"/>
 <xsl:variable name="result" select="number(concat($int,'.',$dec))"/>
 <xsl:variable name="sum" select="$sum + $result" />
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can anybody help me, THX!

```html
  <Details>
   <Package>
    <Items>
     <ItemSeqNo>1</ItemSeqNo>
     <Type>0</Type>
     <INumber>1</INumber>
     <IWeight>1,000</IWeight>
     <IDescription>A</IDescription>
     <Length>010</Length>
     <Height>030</Height>
     <Width>020</Width>
    </Items>
    <Items>
     <ItemSeqNo>2</ItemSeqNo>
     <Type>0</Type>
     <INumber>1</INumber>
     <IWeight>2,500</IWeight>
     <IDescription>B</IDescription>
     <Length>020</Length>
     <Height>040</Height>
     <Width>030</Width>
    </Items>
    <TotalPieces>2</TotalPieces>
    <TotalWeight>3,500</TotalWeight>
    <TotalVolume>0,030</TotalVolume>
   </Package>
  </Details>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal subset of your XML file so we can see what's in those attributes you are using?

Comment: @Sebastien I edited my post with a brief example of my xml

Comment: I know that there is TotalWeight under Items but it wasn't setted for all the Packages in the entire XML

Comment: It doesn't work because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redefine a variable in XSLT. You $sum variable is defined as 0 and can't be redefined.

Your code works fine if you don't reuse the $sum variable.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Details/Package/Items">
        <xsl:variable name="int" select="substring-before(IWeight,',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="dec" select="substring-after(IWeight, ',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result" select="number(concat($int,'.',$dec))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sum" select="$result" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvD

Edit:

Here is how you could get the sum of IWeight for each Details node :

```
<xsl:template match="/Details">
    <xsl:variable name="weight">
        <xsl:for-each select="Package/Items/IWeight">
            <w>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,',','.')"/>
            </w>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum($weight/w)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehVZvvD/1

Based on this previous answer :[XSLT 1.0 how to sum values with commas using sum() - walking in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883703/xslt-1-0-how-to-sum-values-with-commas-using-sum-walking-in-xpath?rq=1)

Comment: No sorry, but the result of your template returns like concat(1,2.5)=12.5 but i need to do 1+2.5=3.5

Comment: So what you want is the sum of all IWeight in your document?

Comment: Yes for each details in my xml i want the sum of items weight but before i have to parse it

Comment: Surelly i don't know to use it but when i call this template apache fop give me this error:  org.apache.xpath.objects.XRTreeFrag cannot be cast to org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, you need to use a `node-set()` extension function if you want to sum the elements in a *result tree fragment* (which is what the variable contains in this example). Or use a recursive named template to produce the sum incrementally.